# accessing a child element and binding it to an event while dynamically creating nested elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks in advance to all first and I also apologize if the title for the question is misleading. I didnt know how to quite word my issue. Again I apologize. Now onto my question...

I was recently given the task to create a login popup for the site I am working on. Long story short, there will be a link for "login" in each and every page on the site. On clicking the link, a popup/balloon will open up with the form elements "username & password" and a button.

Now I created the login popup using jquery ( since the page uses jquery anyway) fadeIn and fadeOut APIs.

This example can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/8am2jecu/ .

The above example is working fine the way I want it to. Now here comes the issue. As I had mentioned earlier, this functionality is going to go on every page. Hence for the sake of code efficiency, I thought of creating this whole nested elements on the fly using jQuery and call the function when the element is clicked.

Hence I came up with this second example http://jsfiddle.net/8yw7c6j6/ .

In the second example the fadeIn API is functioning properly but the fadeOut is not.

Here is the relevant code for the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#clickme").click(function(){
                $('body').append('<div id="popupLogin"><div id="login_content"><p id="exit" style="float:right;">&Chi;</p><div id="input_block"><form action="" method="" style="text-align: center;"><strong>Username&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><input name="" type="text" size="25" class="inputField" /><br><strong>&nbsp;Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><input name="" type="password" size="25" class="inputField" /></form><button type="submit">Login</button></div></div></div>');
                $("#popupLogin").fadeIn(900);
            });

            $("#exit").click(function(){
                $("#popupLogin").fadeOut(700);
            });
        });
```

as opposed to just having a section of html code inside the body section like here...

```
<div id="popupLogin">
        <div id="login_content">
            <p id="exit" style="float:right;">&Chi;</p>
            <div id="input_block">
                <form action="" method="" style="text-align: center;">
                    <strong>Username&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    <input name="" type="text" size="25" class="inputField" />
                    <br>
                    <strong>&nbsp;Password&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
                    <input name="" type="password" size="25" class="inputField" />
                </form>
                <button type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am i missing? also if my way of thinking regarding to code efficiency is flawed please advice me what would be better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the `#exit` is created dynamically you need to use event delegation on the element: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8yw7c6j6/1/)**

```
$(document).on('click',"#exit",function(){
    $("#popupLogin").fadeOut(700);
});
```

also with my taste, there's nothing wrong with your approach.